# Firefox on tablet is adding a blue pointer to inputs

Tags: css, firefox

I'm developing for my company a webapp using JS/HTML5/CSS3, to be used in Firefox exclusively.

The app being used both in "computer" style or with tablet and stiletto, we created a few input environment to help our employees when completing the forms. One of those is a lightened "keyboard" for numeric inputs :

[image: normal behaviour]

Since the last update (Firefox ESR 60.2.1), when clicking inside the input with a stiletto, a blue pin appears, masking the custom keyboard :

[image]

The behaviour only appears when focusing on the input via a styletto, not with a mouse or a touchpad.
Do you have any idea how I could hide this pointer? I tried the following css styles :

```
/*Try 1*/
input{
  cursor:none;
  pointer-events:none;
}

/*Try 2*/
input{
  cursor:none !important;
  pointer-events:none !important;
}

/*Try 3*/
input:focus{
  cursor:none;
  pointer-events:none;
}

/*Try 4*/
input:focus{
  cursor:none !important;
  pointer-events:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input {
  caret-shape: bar;
  caret-color: black;
}
```

Or this

```
input {
  caret-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: the "blue pin" isn't affected by this. It stays there, and it stays blue :(